# In C, missing link between "Main process ends" to "call any functions registered with atexit"

Tags: c, process, program-entry-point, atexit

In C, when the main process ends -- how does it know to call any functions registered with `atexit()`?

I understand how `atexit()` works, but I don't understand the communication between "Main process ending" and "call any functions registered with `atexit()`" I'm being a bit redundant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) [PDF Link] (5.1.2.2.3):

> a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument; reaching the `}` that terminates the main function returns a value of `0`.

It is the responsibility of the `exit` function to call the functions registered with `atexit` (see 7.20.4.3 in the standard for a description of everything that `exit` does).

Comment: Yes, I was stepping though the code of exit, and noticed it has an explicit call to atExit().
Is there another way to do this by playing around with stack (without overrwriting the return address) so that it enters myExit() function when Main ends.

Thanks!

Comment: More likely the compiler emits code which: initializes globals; then calls main; then calls exit with the return value from main.

Answer (score 6):

In C, the `main()` function is actually called by some other function, which is built into the runtime. This function, after the `main()` function ends, does a few more things to clean up. One of them is to call any functions which have been registered with the `atexit()`. This function actually stores some kind of static list of function pointers, which will be called by the runtime after `main()`.

Comment: The file is often called crt0.o; it basically does the setup work, then executes `exit(main(argc, argv));`